# Libgdx android app remove fullscreen and show titlebar

Tags: android, libgdx

Here is a link to a doubt i have regarding my app.Any kind of help to solve this will be appreciated.
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/103610/68334

Comment: I believe you have a `AndroidLauncher` class in Android module. Go in there to configure `AndroidApplicationConfiguration` to whatever you want before passing it to the framework.

Comment: What should i edit in this??

Comment: Please post your `AndroidLauncher` code here so we can help.

Comment: StackOverflow questions should not be links to questions elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after checking through the files, I believe the following configurations will work for your case.

In styles.xml, declares GdxTheme.

```
<style name="GdxTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml, set application theme to `android:theme="@style/GdxTheme"`.

This is all you will need to make the status bar visible.

Comment: Oh really? What Android version are you running your code on?

Comment: Doesn't have any issue here with Lollipop. Can you please create a new LibGDX project and try the suggestion above?